# How to use Redux-Saga with Hooks to call API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to use Redux-saga middleware to avoid the async functions error , I am using React Hooks , I connected the Redux-Saga and did the function* yield functions but I do not know why It is not reading my action to intercept it and it gives me the same error:

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Code:
Store.js

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from './RootReducer'
import {watchFetchImages} from '../middleware/saga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
  );
  sagaMiddleware.run(watchFetchImages);

export default store;
```

Actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GetCategories } from './actionTypes'
import {GetImages} from './actionTypes'

export function fetchCategories() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:4000/all_categories';
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: GetCategories,
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
    } 
}


export function fetchImages(){
    var url ='/all_categories';
    return(dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(url).then((res)=>{
            dispatch({
                type:GetImages,
                payload:res.data
            })  

        })
    }
}
```

Reducers.js

```
import { GetCategories , GetImages } from "../redux/actions/actionTypes"
const initialState = {
    categories: [],
    images:[]
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GetCategories:
            return {...state, categories: state.categories.concat(action.payload)}
        case GetImages:
            return{...state,images:action.payload}
        default:
        return state;

    }
};
export default rootReducer;
```

Saga.js

```
import {takeEvery,delay} from 'redux-saga/effects'



function* getImagesAsync(){
    yield delay(4000);
    console.log('api called')


}
export function* watchFetchImages(){

    yield takeEvery("GetImages",getImagesAsync);


}
```

Home.js Where I call the redux action

```
const  HomePage = props => {



    useEffect(()=>props.getImages())
    console.log(props)

 const mapStateToProps = (images) => ({
        images
    })
    const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch =>({

        getImages: () => dispatch(fetchImages())
    })

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from '../src/redux/store';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Anyone can help me with this ??

Comment: How do you use the `<Provider>` when passing the `store` to it? Could you please share `index.js` as well? Thanks!

Comment: @norbitrial I did add the index.js , If you have any additional comments in addition to the Problem I have please notify my , I am still new to redux and hooks

Comment: In `Saga.js` are you exporting as well `watchFetchImages` function or just missing from the example?

Comment: @norbitrial It is exported in the example do I need to export the other function too getImagesAsync?

Comment: It's true what the error says. I use Redux Thrunk to create functions in the actions. https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk

Comment: @arvie The custom middleware here is `createSagaMiddleware` from `redux-saga` so I guess no need for `redux-thunk` here.

Comment: @arvie I am trying to use SagaMiddleware instead of Thunk

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on a project a few weeks ago that uses redux-saga to deal with websockets and I had an almost simular problem. The SageMidddleware works indeed for the saga functions but to use functions for the actions I use redux-thrunk. Small example:

```js
import { 
 createStore, 
 applyMiddleware, 
 compose 
} from "redux";

import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'; 
import thunk from "redux-thunk"; 

import reducer from '../reducers';

const storeEnhancers =  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
 reducer,
 (localStorage['storage']) ? JSON.parse(localStorage['storage']) : {},
 storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, thunk))
);
```

I hope this helps you in any way possible.

Comment: Thanks , but I need to use Sagas only

Answer (score 0):

So I don't see any issues with `store` setup, `applyMiddleware` is on the correct place. The problem what I see is in generator functions you can call `dispatch` however there are several drawbacks read further here: [Dispatching actions to the store](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DispatchingActions.html).

Instead you can call `put` to dispatch actions. By **creating effect** the **middleware will take care of that** and will dispatch the proper action to the store. So as a better solution from the [documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DispatchingActions.html) which states:

> Instead, we need the same declarative solution. Create a plain JavaScript Object to instruct the middleware that we need to dispatch some action, and let the middleware perform the real dispatch. This way we can test the Generator's dispatch in the same way: by inspecting the yielded Effect and making sure it contains the correct instructions.
>
> The library provides, for this purpose, another function put which creates the dispatch Effect.

Try the following change in `Saga.js`:

```
function* getImagesAsync() {
    // here you can call your API
    const payloadImages = // result from API response

    yield put({type: 'GetImages', payloadImages});
}

export default function* watchFetchImages() {
    yield takeEvery('GetImages', getImagesAsync);
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I tried to do this Still same error , I tried to add another action case in reducer to deal with the saga middleware still same error , I think the error comes from that the takeEvery function do not recognize the action 'GetImages' so it is not intercepting it , still do not know how to fix it my new code :

Saga.js
`function* getImagesAsync(){

    const payloadImages = axios.get('/all_images');;
    yield put({type: 'GetImagesSaga', payload:payloadImages});     
 }

export function* watchFetchImages(){
    yield takeEvery("GetImages",getImagesAsync);
}`